# Critical issue - While Updating the edmx Model in MVC project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, edmx

I am working on the MVC project, I have used the Entity Framework 5.0 and Generated the Model (edmx file) from SQL database, This model gives me the Auto generated Class files for Each table. I have made some changes in these class files for Validation messages and all things.

Now issue is, whenever I am going to Update the Model (edmx file) then it will generate the Class files but my changes are gone, means My changes in class files for validation and all things are no longer available into the model.

So I have facing the critical issue every time updating the model through database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Partial Classes for your customisation. Leave the generated files alone, they will regenerate every time you make any change.

```
public partial class ClassThatIsAlsoInTheEDMX
{
    public string MyCustomFunction()
    {
        return "Wow, this is exciting";
    }
}
```

When this is compiled the generated EDMX class (which is also a partial class) and your partial class are combined and act as one object.

More details here http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/31/entity-framework-using-partial-classes-to-add-business-logic-and-validation-to-generated-entities/

Comment: If the validations are done by **DataAnnotations Attributes**, then using partial classes cannot be used. Same property names cannot be defined in partial views.

Comment: You are correct. You can (perhaps should) get round this by using view models with the DataAnnotations on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModels in your project and in these viewmodels you can define validation attributes. And give these viewmodels to your views as models.

You can map Entities to your ViewModels by creating Mapper methods or by using libraries like AutoMapper.

For custom mapping check: "Mapping Helper Class" section of http://www.adamriddick.com/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-4-your-first-application-part-3/

In that tutorial you can also find the use of ViewModels.

I hope it helps..